# How to browse website published using Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

As part of my learning, I am trying to publish a website and webapi using Azure Service Fabric ASP.NET Core. I am able to publish locally and browse the website using "http localhost".

However, when I publish it to the cloud, I am able to see the Explorer using
"http demoapp.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer"

I remote logged into load balancer node, and able to browse my website using http://10.0.0.5 (i.e. based on the current available nodes)

But, to browse the published website externally, which IP address or URL I should use. How to configure particular IP address or URI to my published website.

I have tried sample application also available at Channel9, "channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B874". It is successfully published. But I am not sure which URI, I have to use to browse this application

Comment: This can be closed as Typo/Unrepro: _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to open the 8080 port and access the site using http demoapp.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:8080.

Answer (score 0):

> to browse the published website externally, which IP address or URL I should use

As I know, If you want to access the site externally, you could use the url: http demoapp.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com. http://10.0.0.5 is only could accessed from the local node.